# Are LINQ .Last, .Skip, etc. methods optimized for arrays or List<T>?

Tags: linq, arrays, optimization

I'm wondering if LINQ methods like `.Last` and `.Skip` are optimized for arrays, `List<T>` and such. E.g. for an array I could do `_array[_array.Length - 1]` to get the last element. Does `_array.Last()` actually enumerate through all elements and then return the last or is there actually some optimization built in?

Might have to forgo fluency for performance if not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Last()` is optimized when there *isn't* a predicate... it *could* be optimized even if there is a predicate (by working back from the end), but it isn't.

I don't *think* `Skip` is optimized - although again, it could be.

Basically *most* of LINQ to Objects is optimized where it can be (for `ICollection<T>`, `ICollection`, and `IList<T>`) but there's still room for more to come.

Comment: Thanks. Do you by chance have the link to the documentation stating the optimization? I was searching for but couldn't find it.